# One .msi file and one .exe file merged into one setup.exe file (2 in 1)

Tags: installation

So what I want is one .msi file and one .exe file merged into one file and when you put the path in the file that we merged both file will install into the path.
Are there any tools to make it happen?

I have tried searching google but I still couldn't find any information.